# Docker file to clone the files which are in git

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I have a server.xml files for 50 applications which are different for all the applications. i need to write a docker file for all the applications to grab that server.xml.

Where is server.xml: Gitserver private repo uses ssh based clone only
I cannot clone complete repo only for single server.xml file

what is the best approach to grab that file and make part of dockerfile.
Is there any way to do it instead of keeping in dockerfile?

Comment: You really need to make it clearer what you are trying to do. Each application has a different server.xml and its own github repo? You need 50 different Docker containers? Why wouldn't you want your server.xml in the Docker container? ("keeping in dockerfile" doesn't really make sense).

Comment: All those xml files will be part of docker image.. so to keep in image i should pull files from git repo for which i use docker file.                       For your qstnn Each application has a different server.xml and its own github repo?No we have one private repo which has all the files related to applications. So i need to grab those files and should be part of image

Answer (score 1):

You could [use an argument](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables) to pull the xml file and then build it into the image.

```
FROM alpine
ARG SERVER_CONF
RUN curl ${SERVER_CONF}
EXEC server.sh
```

Then you can run build and pass in the location of the xml file

```
docker build --build-arg SERVER_CONF=http://localhost/server.xml
```

Alternatively you could set this as an environment variable so that you can get the xml file at runtime.

```
FROM alpine
ARG SERVER_CONF
ENV SERVER_CONF=${SERVER_CONF}
RUN server.sh --config=$SERVER_CONF
```

This would allow you to set the config dynamically when you build the image.

If you would like to set the config at runtime then you could pass it as an environment variable when starting the docker container

```
FROM alpine
RUN server.sh --config=$SERVER_CONF
```

Then start your container by [passing in the environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables)

```
docker run -e "SERVER_CONF=http://localhost/server.xml" server
```

You don't have to pass a url, you could pass the entire contents of the xml file as a string. You can use an [entry point](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) to write the contents of the environment to a file before your application starts.

Comment: What does server.sh consists?

Comment: All the xml files are in git repository, so i cannot use curl to grab the xml files.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to do it instead of keeping in dockerfile?

As long as you have fetched that server.xml (or simply copied its content to a local file), you can:

- either [COPY it in your Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)
- or put it in a public place, remotely accessible, which your container could, at runtime, fetch from (instead of having to try and clone a private repo, which your container should not be able to do)